# Print once inside for loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I have this code

```
if(orden[i]==1)
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        if(v[i]<v[i+k])
            printf("print once ");
```

How can I make it so that it prints the line only once, if the condition inside the for loop is satisfied?

Comment: First fix your code formatting and then provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: I've reformatted your code. Please don't post C code as a JavaScript snippet, just use plain code (the `{}` icon).

Comment: I very much recommend the use of parentheses (if not always).

Comment: If I rewrote the `if` inside your `for` to be `if(printf("here\n")&&v[i]<v[i+k])`, how often would you expect `here` to be printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `break` command to exit the `for` loop.

```
if(orden[i]==1)
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        if(v[i]<v[i+k])
        {
            printf("print once "); 
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Also make sure you do not go out of bounds with your array indexing. Assuming v is of size ARRAY_SIZE, i+k should be less than ARRAY_SIZE.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you first change your index variables, to avoid confusion. I suggest using `i` and `j`. And the code would be more or less of the form:

```
if(orden[i]==1)  
  for(j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
    if((j==0)&&(v[j]<v[j+k]))
      printf("print once ");
```

Answer (score 1):

If v[i] isn't great than v[i+k] you exit from the 'while' and than print your value:

```
while ((i < ARRAY_SIZE) && (v[i] > v[i+k])) {
    i++;
}
printf("print once ");
```

Alternative you can use a boolean variable, but is not best solution for memory's reason.